# Dynamic local tasks to the same route with slug

Tags: 8, routes

I have a route set up with a slug accepting taxonomy terms (`routing.yml`):

```
example.column:
  path: '/column/{taxonomy_term}'
```

I would like to add (secondary, although that's not important) local task tabs on a page, one for each possible term of the vocabulary used (`links.task.yml`):

```
example.column_list:
  deriver: 'Drupal\example\Plugin\Derivative\ColumnTasks'
  parent_id: example.parent
```

The deriver is pretty straightforward and simple and mentioned in a few [docs on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks#dynamic-local-task-generation), the relevant part is:

```
foreach ($columns as $column) {
  $route_name = 'example.column';
  $this->derivatives[$route_name] = [
    'title' => $column->getName(),
    'route_name' => $route_name,
    'route_parameters' => ['taxonomy_term' => $column->id()],
    'parent_id' => 'example.parent',
  ] + $base_plugin_definition;
}
```

The problem is that this code, obviously, doesn't generate more than one tab because all go to the same `$route_name`. But I'm not allowed to use any other route name (suffixing it with the term, for instance) because it complains about a non-existent route then.

Do I have any other solution than to generate all the routes separately, using a `_route_callback`? This would somehow feel wrong, going against the reason for the existence of slugs in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array key is *not* the route name, it's the machine name of the local task. It's pretty common to use the same string but that's in no way a requirement.

Just use a different array key and this should work.

Comment: Indeed. I could've sworn I tried that as well but apparently not. Thanks.